# showing error while adding values in to sql using variables in python code

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Whenever I tried to enter new data into the database using SQL query in python it is showing error like" You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your `MariaDB` server version for the right syntax to use near '('employee').

problem is  at `(elif value == 2)` block

```
import pymysql
import time

def student_database():

    storage = input("Enter your database name :")
    table = input("Enter your table name")
    print("Press 1 for Displaying Data -->")
    print("Press 2 for entering new Data..")
    print("press 3 for adding new column to  table..")
    print("press 4 for modifying data in table")
    value = int(input())
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', database=storage, user='', passwd='')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print("Connected to " + storage)

    if value == 1:
        print("Printing Data :\n")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (%s)" %(table))
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
    elif value == 2:
        print("Enter New Values to be entered")
        first = input("Enter First Name: ")
        last = input("Enter Last Name: ")
        age = input("Enter Age: ")
        sex = input("Enter Sex: ")
        salary = input("Enter salary amount: ")
        no = input("Enter number")
        # query for adding data into table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO (%s) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (table, first, last, age, sex, salary, no))
        db.commit()
        print("Data entered Succesfully")

    elif value == 3:
        print("Enter column name to be added")
        column_name = input("enter new column name")
        #query for adding new column in existing table
        cursor.execute("Alter table employee add %s VARCHAR(10)" %column_name)
        db.commit()
        print("column Added successfully")
    elif value == 4:
        field_name = input("enter field name to be updated :")
        new_value = input("Please enter your new value")
        reference_name = input("enter reference column name :")
        reference_value = input("enter reference value :")
        cursor.execute("update employee set %s = %s WHERE %s = %s" % (field_name, new_value, reference_name, reference_value))
        db.commit()
        print("data modified succesfully    ")

while(True):

    student_database()
    time.sleep(3)
```

if `value == 2` it needs to take some inputs and enter the same data into the employee table.

Comment: In your insert statement the string values need to be wrapped in single quotes. That said you've just created a sql injection attack with this and should be using a parameterised query.

Comment: Oh and I'm not sure about the ()  round your table names in you sql strings, unless that's some mysql weirdness I've never run into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for table names in prepared statements. You can only use them for data values. You should change  your cursor.execute statement to:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+table+" VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (first, last, age, sex, salary, no))
```

And I don't see where you give value to your table variable.

Comment: import pymysql
import time

def student_database():

    storage = input("Enter your database name :")
    **table = input("Enter your table name")**

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see it before